# Regresar al inicio de un programa en python

Tags: python

estoy empezando con el lenguaje y tengo una consulta, tengo un programa que calcula área y perímetro de varias figuras.
Deseo que una ves finalizado el programa el mismo me pregunte si deseo continuar, si la respuesta es SI
pueda seguir calculando otras figuras, si es NO me saque del programa

```
print('''-==Bienvenid@, vamos a calcular la area y perimetro de algunas figuras.
Puedes escoger entre un cuadrado, triangulo, trapecio y circulo==-
---------------------------------------------------------------------------''')
opcion = input('Ingresa el nombre de la figura que vamos a calcular: ')
opcion =formatear_texto(opcion).lower()


if opcion == 'cuadrado':
 def calcula_area_cuadrado(l):
    formula_area_cuadrado = l * 2
    return formula_area_cuadrado
 def calcula_perimetro_cuadrado(l):
    formula_perimetro_cuadrado = l * 4
    return formula_perimetro_cuadrado

area_cuadrado = float(
input('Indique el valor de uno de los lados del cuadrado: '))

resultado_area_cuadrado = calcula_area_cuadrado(area_cuadrado)
resultado_perimetro_cuadrado = calcula_perimetro_cuadrado(area_cuadrado)

print('El area del cuadrado es ', resultado_area_cuadrado,', mientras el perimetro es:', resultado_perimetro_cuadrado)
```

Esto es un resumen del codigo, tengo otras funciones que calculan otras figuras.
gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: mete todo tu codigo en un bucle `while`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes resolverlo de varias maneras, con un `while` que verifica una variable cuyo valor indica si se desea continuar o no, y también puedes hacerlo con una función recursiva aunque como se me ha echo notar en un comentario esta sería la opción menos recomendable.

### Ciclo While

```
while True:

    # todo tu código

    continuar = input('Desea continuar? S / N :')

    if continuar.lower() in "s si y yes":
        continue

    else:
        break
```

Esta opción es la más recomendable, se trata de un ciclo infinito que hará que el código se repita mientras la variable `continuar` no indique de interrumpir el ciclo.

### Función recursiva

```
def programa():

    # todo tu código

    continuar = input('Desea continuar? S / N :')

    if continuar.lower() in "s si y yes":
        # vuelve a ejecutar el programa
        programa()
```

Como puedes ver, se trata de colocar todo tu código al interno de una función y em caso de querer volver a ejecutar tu código simplemente haces que esa función se llame a si misma.

La condición `if` simplemente controla si el valor que fue dado en input es igual a una de las palabras o letras de la string, ahí debes colocar cualquier carácter o palabra que deseas que sea empleada para que el programa se vuelva a ejecutar.

Comment: Ariel, aunque la solución que aportas efectivamente funcionaría, no me parece que sea apropiado mostrar a alguien que está aprendiendo un código que es más bien un **antipatrón**. La forma natural de resolver lo que pide es con un bucle `while` y no con recursión. La recursividad es más pesada que el bucle, y además en el caso de python que no tiene optimización de tipo recursión de cola, cada repetición del bucle crearía un nuevo marco de pila, consumiendo más memoria (y pudiendo llegar a un stack overflow si se repite demasiadas veces)

Comment: No sabía eso, gracias. Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, me fui con la primera opción y me funciono, en realidad ya había implementado unj while pero no funcionaba por identacion, pero con tu ejemplo pude ver tu identacion y me funco.
Lo de la función recursiva es un tema que aun no abarco.

Answer (score 0):

Si describes con pseudocódigo (es decir, en castellano) lo que buscas, sería algo como:

- Repetir

  - (todo tu código)
  - preguntar al usuario si quiere otra vez
- mientras la respuesta sea "Sí".

Esta estructura de código es un bucle. De hecho sería un bucle del tipo `do`/`while` (haz esto mientras sea verdad esto otro). En los bucles de tipo `do/while` la condición para ver si se repite el bucle o no se evalúa al final del mismo.

Por desgracia Python carece de bucle `do`/`while`. Tiene en cambio un bucle de tipo `while`, en el que la condición para decidir si el bucle se repite o no se mira al principio del mismo. Es decir, la estructura del programa ha de ser:

- Mientras (cierta condición sea cierta) repite lo siguiente

  - Bloque de código

Por lo que tenemos que pensar cómo adaptar a este estilo tu caso. La solución típica consiste en tener una variable booleana (una que puede valer `True` o `False`) e inicializarla con `True` antes de entrar al `while`. En la condición del `while` se pondría esa variable, que al ser cierta garantiza que el bucle se hará al menos una vez. Al final del bloque while se actualiza ese booleano de modo que le haremos `False` si no queremos repetir más el bucle.

Por tanto en tu caso sería (en pseudocódigo) algo así:

- quiere_seguir = `True`
- Mientras quiere_seguir:

  - (todo tu código)
  - preguntar al usuario si quiere otra vez
  - actualizar variable `quiere_seguir`

Lo cual en Python quedará así:

```
quiere_seguir = True
while quiere_seguir:
  # Todo tu código
  respuesta = input("Otra vez? ")
  if respuesta.lower() in ["no", "n"]:
     quiere_seguir = False
```

### Otra forma

Otra forma de hacer este tipo de bucles consiste en plantear un *bucle infinito* (uno cuya condición es siempre cierta), pero romper el bucle con `break` cuando se quiera salir de él. Así:

```
while True:
   # Todo tu codig
  respuesta = input("Otra vez? ")
  if respuesta.lower() in ["no", "n"]:
     break
```

Este enfoque está mal visto por los puristas de la programación estructurada, porque consideran que el `break` es una especie de "goto" que nunca debería usarse. Sin embargo se ve muy a menudo en la práctica y yo personalmente no le pongo ningún pero.

Comment: Uff exc explicación.
Gracias.

Comment: De nada! No olvides aceptar alguna de las respuestas que has recibido, para que el tema quede cerrado.